# system php возвращает NULL

Tags: php, mp3, exec

Добрый день!
Есть необходимость поменять битрейт песни прямо на сервере(centos, php, mysql, apache). Для этого использую lame

На локальном сервере все работает отлично, а вот на глобальном ничего не происходит. Вот такую команду я использую

```
exec("lame -b 128 ".$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$mp3_name." ".$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/music/'.$dataf['last_id_file'].".mp3");
```

Comment: Передайте второй параметр в [exec](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.exec.php), в нем будет полученный вывод. У вас может `lame` не стоит, либо прав на запуск нету, либо еще что. Как вариант - вывести на экран команду, которую пытаетесь исполнить и запустить ее ручками. От ошибок с правами на запуск не избавитесь, но хотя бы будете уверенны, что такая команда вообще может выполниться нормально.

Comment: lame точно установлен, я его даже запускал с консоли на глобальном сервере.Все работает. Если добавить второй аргумент в exec то через var_dump эта переменная выглядит так array(0){ }(локальний сервер), попробовал использовать passthru($com, $out_code) на локальном возвращает 0, на глобальном ничего, а точнее через var_dump NULL

Comment: Возможно exec внесен в disabled_functions в настройках php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверьте не включен ли safe_mode для php. Так же может быть включено ограничение использования функций php - [disable_functions](http://php.net/manual/ru/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions).

Ещё может быть, что у пользователя, от которого запускается веб-сервер, отсутствует оболочка. Попробуйте выполнить:`echo exec("whoami");`
После получения ответа, проверьте есть ли валидная оболочка в файле /etc/passwd: `echo exec("cat /etc/passwd");`.

Как вариант можно ещё выводить результат выполнения команды в файл: `exec("/usr/bin/some_command > /full/path/to/root/dir/log.txt");`

Но скорее всего команда `lame` отсутствует в директориях поиска бинарников для пользователя, от которого происходит запуск. С консоли на сервере сделайте `which lame`, после чего исправьте Вашу команду, указав полный путь до бинарника, например `exec("/usr/local/bin/lame [options] [filename]");`

Comment: Достаточно было убрать нужные функции с  disable_functions, спасибо большое!